# How to get the css value from outer html structure using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have the following html code

```
   <div id="im" style="width:20px; color:red;" >12</div>
```

i need to get this html structure `<div id="im" style="width:20px; color:red;" >` to a variable . How i get this ?

To get the text , or content inside the div we can use

```
$( "#im" ).html();
```

But i want to get the htm structure , not the content . Please help.

> **Edit**

i understand that we can use `$( "#im" ).prop('outerHTML');`

From this result how can i get the `width` ?

i know we can use .css("width"), but i need to get this from `prop('outerHTML')`.

Please help .

Comment: `$( "#im" ).prop('outerHTML');`

Comment: This seems to be XY problem. What is you exact issue?

Comment: i need output like this var outer= $( "#im" ).prop('outerHTML'); .from this outer variable , i need to get the width .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property of DOM element object. Where you can get [DOM element from jQuery objec](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)t using the index.

```
$("#im")[0].outerHTML
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** To get the width from attribute use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get attribute value and [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to get the style property value using regex from the string.

```js
console.log(
  $('#im').attr('style').match(/width\s?:([^;]+)/)[1]
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="im" style="width:20px; color:red;">12</div>
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :**  Although you can get the calculated with property using [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

```js
console.log(
  $('#im').css('width')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="im" style="width:20px; color:red;">12</div>
```

---

**UPDATE 3 :**  To get it from the string wrap it with jQuery and do the same.

```js
console.log(
  $($('#im')[0].outerHTML).css('width')
)

// or

console.log(
  $($('#im')[0].outerHTML).attr('style').match(/width\s?:([^;]+)/)[1]
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="im" style="width:20px; color:red;">12</div>
```

Comment: No.i need output like this var outer= $( "#im" ).prop('outerHTML');  .from this outer variable , i need to get the width .

Comment: Could you please check this for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372272/how-to-use-an-api-for-international-gold-rate

Comment: @Jafartm better to use html parser

Comment: could you please check that . HTML Parser and api is something i didn't get

Comment: @Jafartm : ok may be later